# Line of code in a coroutine scope after a suspend method call not executing

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, kotlin-coroutines, android-paging

After calling a suspend method inside a CoroutineScope launch block, the code after the suspend call is not executing.

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
            adapter.source!!.submit(page as PagingData<Receipt>)//suspend call
            
            //not executing
            if (setInitialItem) {
                Log.d("INITIALSET", "set initial")
                pager.currentItem = intent.getIntExtra(POSITION, 0)
            }
        }
```

The submit method is defined in androidx.paging.AsyncPagingDataDiffer

```java
//snippet
suspend fun submitData(pagingData: PagingData<T>) {
        submitDataId.incrementAndGet()
        differBase.collectFrom(pagingData)
    }
```

Comment: Can you show this `submit` function? Something is preventing it from returning or completing.

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: When lunching a function without specifying the Dispachers you would use is lunching the suspended method on the main thread, until `submitData` call would not end the if statement will not execute. If  you would add `(Dispaches,IO)` to the `lunch` function I believe it will solve the issue.